# swf not showing up?

Tags: wordpress, themes, flash

I have a wordpress theme I'm adapting to a clients needs, but I can't make the sidebar ads, which are 125x125px, show a same sized swf instead of a image. If I insert a swf link, it show a broken image thumbnail. 
Please help me achieve this. 
If it helps you, the url of the website is http://infodrum.ro/inde2.php/

PHP code

```
<?php if(get_theme_option('ads_125') != '') {
?>
    <div class="sidebaradbox">
        <?php sidebar_ads_125(); ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

CSS

```
.ad125 {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 125px;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide some code here - otherwise, the question will become worthless to future reader once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're usually inserting a path to an image in The backend, right? Like "http://somedomain.com/image.jpg"

Most likely, The Code Inside The Plugin then Produces something like

```
<img src="WHATEVER YOU ENTERED" />
```

Since an SWF is Not a valid image, everything ends up being terrible.

I suggest you try The normal WP Text Widget instead!

Comment: So if I insert it in the code manually, it should work, right?

Comment: This is going to Be kinda hacky, but generally speaking: Yes. Just throw it into your template to See if it Shows up.